# Why (and when) was `dos` removed as a Matlab Built-In function?

Tags: matlab

Somewhere between R2010b and R2018a, Matlab seems to have removed `dos` as a built-in function.

In R2010b:

```
>> which dos
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\general\dos)
```

In R2018a:

```
>> which dos
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\matlab\general\dos.m
```

Why, and when, was this change made?

Comment: This is something only The MathWorks can answer, not random people on the internet. My hunch is that, since it still exists, the name "built-in" was used for everything that came with MATLAB, whilst nowadays it's only used for stuff written in another language and compiled and shipped along (see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50832559/5211833))

Comment: In R2010b type `edit dos`. I think you will see the same M-file function as you see if you do that in R2018a. If so, then nothing changed.

Comment: The 2018a version of `dos.m` does contain a call out to `system()`, but the 2010b version is just help documentation (no code).

Comment: Then indeed it has been converted from a built-in function to M-file code. There is no way we can know about the reasons. The M-file code should contain a copyright statement, you might be able to see when they wrote that code. :)

Comment: Ah! The copyright is from 2016, so the change must have happened somewhere between 2010 and 2016.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file *dos.m* you can notice that is a wrapper to the built-in function 
*system* so the answar might be that MathWorks has improved the *system* function to run correctly both Windows command and Unix command so a built-in function for a wrapper is useless due the definition of built-in function:

A built-in function is part of the MATLAB executable. MATLAB does not implement these functions in the MATLAB language. Although most built-in functions have a .m file associated with them, this file only supplies documentation for the function.

Comment: In 2010b, the documentation declares that `dos()` is interchangeable with `system()` (in Windows). It seems like they removed `dos()` as its own code path, and have changed it to be an m-file that calls out to `system()`. But I'm wondering why they would have made this change, as calls to `builtin('dos',…` fail in 2018a.

Comment: @JeffV if dos and system are interchangeable since 2010b it is more right the choice of remove it as built-in function. Maybe they did some statistic of use of built-in function and they saw that most of time users call system, so they had removed dos as built-in function and had made a wrapper to system for portability